# Uploading files to a test website over 1 GB in size using python and playwright library

Tags: python, upload, playwright

I am having trouble uploading files larger than 1GB.
I applied the code included in the link:
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-filechooser/
The code:

```
with page.expect_file_chooser() as fc_info:
    page.click("upload")
file_chooser = fc_info.value
file_chooser.set_files("/path/to/a/file")
```

When I run my script, I get an error message:

```
File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_transport.py", line 149, in send
len(data).to_bytes(4, byteorder="little", signed=False) + data
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

Someone can tell me how to bypass the problem.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very common bug and it is impossible with this software in real systems. Contact an official developer or choose another professional solution.

Comment: Additional question: is this bug present in all previous versions of playwright lib?